# Promise in a service cancelling itself

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-promise, angular-http

I'm running into a bit of a problem with an Angular (1.4) service. The code is roughly as follows :

```
    service.retrieveStuffFromServer = function() {
        return httpCallFromServer().then(
            function(data) {
                if (Array.isArray(data)) {
                    return data;
                }
                return [];
            }
        );
    };
```

I call this function in two distinct controllers. Most of the times, it works as intended, but I'm having problem in those conditions :

- The HTTP call takes time to return the data
- Controller A calls the service.
- Controller B calls the service.
- The service returns data to controller A
- The call in the controller B is cancelled. The logic after it never executes

My first guess would be to slightly alter the service, to inform either of the controllers if the service is already busy so I can retry later, but I'm not sure if this is the best solution, so I'm looking for some advice.

Comment: Or do you want two calls to return the same result, i.e. cached?

Comment: the point is to only call the service data once, from any controller ? Why the call in controller B is canceled, and how ?

Comment: What parts of that condition description are the steps to reach it, and what part is the problematic behaviour (and what should happen instead)?

Comment: @Bergi, the last part of the steps is the problematic part. What should normally happen is, the service returns the data to both controllers A and B. Instead, the logic in B isn't executed.

Comment: That's weird, this should not happen. Can you show us your exact code? There might be a bug in there. Also, what do your devtools say, does the second request succeed on the HTTP layer? Do you have error handlers?

Comment: @Bergi, to be honest the angularJS code is pretty straightforward, but as I said in another comment there's several layers that I don't control between the code and the device and it could be that something is happening there.

Comment: @lbreakjai: Even straightforward code can have bugs :-) Please [edit] your post to show it

Comment: @Bergi, I'll paste the relevant code tomorrow morning once I have it in front of me :-) Thanks for you time!

Comment: You need `return` in front of `httpCall` if this is remotely real code.

Comment: @Bergi the code in the original post have been updated to reflect the real code. I just changed some names to be more explicit.

Comment: @lbreakjai: Hm, that seems about fine (assuming it's not `httpCallFromServer()` that screws up). Again, can you check whether there are any errors/rejections?

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say why it doesn't just work, but presumably something in `httpCall()` is preventing the same call from being made again before the 1st one completes, and it rejects if that happens. But if you want controller B call to share the response from an active previous call, you could cache the promise:

```
function myFunction() {
   if (!myFunction.promise) {
     myFunction.promise = httpCall()
         .then(function(result) { 
             myFunction.promise = undefined;
             return ...
         }, function(err) {
             myFunction.promise = undefined;
             throw err;
         });
    }
    return myFunction.promise;
 }
```

This will cause the same promise from a prior call to be returned as long as the prior call is still unresolved.

Using a property of the function itself as a cache is a convenient way to keep state associated logically with the function itself. You could just use any variable defined outside the scope of `myFunction` though.

Comment: You probably want to `throw err`, not `return` it. Or just use `.finally` instead.

Comment: There's several steps and transformations involved between the moment the code is written and the moment it runs on Android/iOS, and I didn't see a reason why it behaves the way it does.

It isn't straightforward to reproduce either and requires to fiddle with Charles a little bit.

Thank you very much for your answer, I'll try that as soon as I can.

Comment: `finally` is not part of the actual promise spec, it's a library-specific extension. Since I don't know what promise library, if any, he's using, I chose to wrote code that would work anywhere. `catch` would be OK but isn't any shorter. You're right about returning err, thanks, fixed!